# Lunch menu for WordPress with advanced custom fields

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm building a website for business with lunch menu list on their website. How could i do this menu so that admin could write this weeks menu and it will display today's lunch on their website using advanced custom fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the past weeks menu doesn't need to stay, i.e. they will only be concerned with “this week's menu” this should be pretty straightforward. You could create an ACF Field Group called Lunch Menu, and within that, do a repeater field for containing the various items, such as “Salad, $4.50”. The specifics are really up to you. You would also want to set this field group to only show on the Lunch Page Template. The ACF Docs have pretty much all the info on creating a Repeater field that you'd need! Good luck! https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/repeater/